# C# upcast generic type to interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, polymorphism

This is similar to another topic I recently posted, but perhaps this might be simpler and clearer:

I want to accomplish the following (or something very similar)...

```
IManageableEntryDao<IManageableEntry> dao = new CompanyNameDao();
```

... with the following classes:

```
public interface IManageableEntry {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyName : IManageableEntry {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IManageableEntryDao<T> where T : IManageableEntry {
}

public class CompanyNameDao : IManageableEntryDao<CompanyName> {
}
```

If I try to do a cast `as IManageableEntryDao<IManageableEntry>`, I get a null.

Comment: So this wont be doable in C# 3.5?

Comment: Sadly, no. At least, not directly. You'll have to find a workaround, e.g. making `CompanyNameDao` inherit from `IManageableEntryDao<IManageableEntry>`; that's your call to make.

Comment: Right, that's less elegant because then the CompanyNameDao is returning IManageableEntry objects rather than CompanyName objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059).  Change the interface to `IManageableEntryDao<out T>` and it should work (unless the interface uses it in a way which makes this invalid).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) for this to work. This feature is only available in C# 4.0. What you need to do:

```
public interface IManageableEntryDao<out T> where T : IManageableEntry { }
```